# Cannot change brightness on Sony VAIO Fit 15

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sony-vaio, brightness

I've begun to notice that periodically on my Sony VAIO Fit 15 (model number SVF15A1C5E) I can no longer change the screen brightness. Using the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> shows Windows 8 the brightness overlay, but the screen brightness doesn't actually change, and the option in Power Options also has no effect. The problem can sometimes be alleviated by rebooting.

[This YouTube video illustrates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=su34WRmwEsE) the same problem I'm experiencing, although it's a different VAIO model.

Having reviewed the recommendations on [this Microsoft Community discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/sony-vaio-laptop-upgrade-to-windows-81-brightness/f915bf10-bb69-4246-95ee-46adf2bb41f7), I've tried the following:

- Upgraded to the latest Intel HD 4000 and NVIDIA GeForce GT 735M graphics drivers (10.18.10.3412 and 334.89, respectively)
- Upgraded to the latest version of VAIO Control Center (6.2.11.09270)
- Disabled the "Enable adaptive brightness" option in all power plans, despite my model not having an ambient light sensor:
  [image: Power plan settings]
- Checked for a "Screen brightness" setting in VAIO Control Center, under "Image Quality"; no such option exists:
  [image: VAIO Control Center, Image Quality]

Some have recommended to only use graphics drivers provided through Sony. I've tried this in the past, only to see the same problem. Nevertheless, VAIO Update does show an older version for my NVIDIA graphics card (from October 2013).

Has anybody else experienced this? Is there a way to definitively resolve this specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I have just fixed it.
It may sound like the most obvious solution ever but I installed the last version of the Nvidia controller from Sony webpage and it worked.
Keep in mind that my VAIO is not the same, is the Fit14 with a 735M graphics card

Answer (score 0):

Paul, there are many keyboard shortcuts to change your brightness up and down.

One is FN + X to adjust it.

Also, taken from here : http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7367-windows-vista-7-changing-the-brightness

> On most laptops, there are already shortcuts to change the brightness. For example:
>   On HP (and other models) is the Fn + F7 to key increase or Fn + F8 to decrease brightness.
>   On IBM ThinkPad, Fn + Home or Fn + End
>   Asus, Fn + F6 to increase, and Fn + F5 to decrease.
>
> You can easily find these shortcuts just by looking on the keyboard. Brightness is often designated by a small sun with an arrow at the top or bottom. **But sometimes we need that the proper driver is installed for these buttons work!**

I don't think you should have updated.

Comment: The suggestion you've linked is ambiguous as one can also interpret it to simply mean that drivers for the keys are needed. In the OP I've illustrated that the keys are not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vaio Brightness issues windows 8.1

It seems multiple people are having this same issue. I installed latest drivers for the intel gpu using driver update from device manager (search online option). Next I downloaded the drivers from AMD for my second gpu.(my model has switching gpus) I installed vaio control center and vaio care. These applications didn't even work. I uninstalled the applications. Restarted. Switched to the intel gpu and the changed the settings under display of the power plan. I set all to 100% and disabled adaptive brightness. Applied the settings then switched to the AMD gpu. The brightness is now at 100% . It looks like the software is creating an issue. Hope this helps someone. I had this issue after a fresh install of windows 8.1